# Execution Plan did not change

Tags: performance, query-performance

[image]
After alter function execution paln did not change.

```
Alter FUNCTION dbo.F_New
(
    @i integer
)
RETURNS DateTime
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    -- Convert with a deterministic style


 RETURN CONVERT(datetime, '19000101', 112);
END;
GO
```

Comment: In the excecution plan posted, you seem to be using the function dbo.F. Could you post the execution plan before and after the change and any other relevant information? Also the execution plan might use different operators, even though you altered the function. Why do you want the execution plan to change?

Comment: What change were you expecting?

Comment: Schema binding how to increase query performance at this example ??

Comment: You already have an optimal plan with a seek. Can you give "before" and "after" versions so we can see what you are testing. I assume this question is about this answer. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140382/3690